# Stubborn zoomed text in Nautilus / Nemo, whichever set as default

Tags: unity, nautilus, text, nemo, zooming

Somehow I have managed to zoom the text size in Nautilus on Ubuntu 16.10, probably because I couldn't originally change the screen resolution and everything was tiny. Now I can't remember how I did it and cannot undo it.

It is not effected by the text-zoom setting in system settings. It also doesn't change when I zoom the icon size in and out. I've tried Unity Tweak tool and CCSM to no avail. I've also tried resetting Unity to defaults.

I eventually gave up and installed Nemo instead. When I set Nemo as the default, Nemo got zoomed text, and Nautilus became normal.

There must be a setting somewhere that I am missing. Any ideas?

[Small text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6sHZ.png)
[Big text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2mVI.png)

Edit:

The result of: 
gsettings list-recursively | grep -P 'nautilus.*(font|zoom)'

```
org.gnome.nautilus.list-view default-zoom-level 'small'
org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view default-zoom-level 'standard'
org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view default-zoom-level 'standard'
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font ''
org.gnome.nautilus.list-view default-zoom-level 'small'
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font ''
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Do you have the same happening in the guest session?

Comment: No, when I create a new account, the problem disappears.

Comment: Run this command in terminal: `gsettings list-recursively | grep -P 'nautilus.*(font|zoom)'` This should list your current settings for zoom level and font type and size.   Click [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/925302/edit) button and add the resulting output to your question. Notice, there's no space between `*` and things in parenthesis

Comment: Results added to original question.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type the following commands: (assuming `user` is your old user name)

```
sudo adduser user2
```

and follow the instructions on-screen.  If you're *not on a US keyboard*, don't use any "special" characters like £ à ŷ ü nor any numbers unless they're from your keypad.

Now type the following commands:

```
sudo adduser user2 adm 
sudo adduser user2 cdrom
sudo adduser user2 sudo
sudo adduser user2 dip
sudo adduser user2 plugdev
sudo adduser user2 lpadmin
sudo adduser user2 sambashare
```

(If any of the above gives an error like `group not found`, don't worry: I'm trying to be thorough)

Log out of this session and log in as `user2`

1. Open the file manager
2. Browse to the `/home/user` directory
3. **Copy** (don't move!) all the *files* from Downloads to `/home/user2/Downloads`
4. Check you did a good job.
5. Now delete `/home/user/Downloads`
6. Go back to step 3 and repeat for Documents, Videos, ...
7. In a terminal type the following command: `deluser user --remove-home`

#### Result:

You have a new user without the problem...